# Maximum number of routes in RIPv2

Tags: cisco, router, routing, rip

What is the limitations of route count in RIPv2? Is there a standard limitation of the protocol or does it vary by router models, configurations, etc...

Comment: Are you referring to the hop count or the number of routes in the routing table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of routes will depend mostly of the amount of RAM you have in the router as there's not such limitation in RIPv2. I should say that in any new network deployment, if there's any chance you'd have more than a couple of routers, you should consider something else than RIP, say, OSPF or IS-IS, which are modern routing protocols, and will do a way better job handling topology changes in any network.

Answer (score 0):

I think without RIP-MTI, hop limit is 15. But other than that it should be similar for most enterprise level routing devices.